# django date input format

Tags: python, django, date, django-forms

I am using Django 1.7 & Python 2.7 and I am using Model Forms.

I have a template that allows date format in a certain way:

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = (

    '%m.  %Y',  # mm.  yyyy (. and two space separator).
    '%m. %Y',  # mm. yyyy (. and one space separator).
    '%m.%Y',  # mm.yyyy (dot separator).
    '%m-%Y',  # mm-yyyy (dash separator).
    '%Y.%m',  # yyyy.mm (dot separator).
    '%Y/%m',  # yyyy/mm (forward slash separator).
    '%Y-%m',  # yyyy-mm (dash separator).
    '%m/%Y',  # mm/yyyy (forward slash separator) (default date format).

)
```

I have set up my Model Form to allow the input format of the date field as:

```
input_formats = {
    'award_grant_date': settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS,
}
```

But the above code always returns an input error as 'Enter a valid date.'

So I did some reading of SO threads and I have entered the following line of code into the init of the Model Form to get the date input working:

```
self.fields['award_grant_date'].input_formats = (settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)
```

So my question is: **Why did the input_formats of the Form Model not work but the code in the init of the Form Model does work?** This may be an easy answer, but I could not find the answer in the docs or SO posts.

Comment: Are you using DateField or DateTimeField? For the latter you need to set `DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS`. Also, documentation doesn't mention setting `input_formats` field on a Form, it's a field attribute https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/fields/, which is why the solution you found works.